# Available locale display country when "inLocale" is set to Turkish (JDK 1.6.0_29)?

Tags: java, locale, java-6, turkish

According to the javadoc for [`Locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale inLocale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry%28java.util.Locale%29),

> Returns a name for the locale's country that is appropriate for
>   display to the user. If possible, the name returned will be localized
>   according to inLocale. For example, if the locale is fr_FR and
>   inLocale is en_US, getDisplayCountry() will return "France"; if the
>   locale is en_US and inLocale is fr_FR, getDisplayCountry() will return
>   "Etats-Unis". If the name returned cannot be localized according to
>   inLocale. (say, we don't have a Japanese name for Croatia), this
>   function falls back on the English name, and finally on the ISO code
>   as a last-resort value. If the locale doesn't specify a country, this
>   function returns the empty string.

So, when I execute the following code snippet:

```
final class TurkishDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Locale l = new Locale("tr");
        for(Locale locale: Locale.getAvailableLocales())
        {
            System.out.println(locale.getDisplayCountry(l));
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the following output:

> Japan Peru
>
> Japan Panama Bosnia and Herzegovina
>
> Guatemala United Arab Emirates Norway Albania
>
> Iraq Yemen
>
> Portugal Cyprus Qatar Macedonia
>
> Switzerland United States Finland
>
> Malta Slovenia Slovakia
>
> **Türkiye**
>
> Saudi Arabia
>
> United Kingdom Serbia and Montenegro
>
> New Zealand Norway Lithuania Nicaragua
>
> Ireland Belgium Spain Lebanon
>
> Canada Estonia Kuwait Serbia United States Mexico Sudan Indonesia
>
> Uruguay Latvia
>
> Brazil Syria
>
> Dominican Republic Switzerland India Venezuela Bahrain Philippines
>   Tunisia
>
> Austria
>
> Netherlands Ecuador Taiwan Jordan
>
> Iceland Colombia Costa Rica Chile Egypt South Africa Thailand Greece
>   Italy
>
> Hungary
>
> Ireland Ukraine Poland Luxembourg Belgium India Spain Morocco Bolivia
>   Australia
>
> Singapore
>
> El Salvador Russia South Korea
>
> Algeria Vietnam Montenegro
>
> Libya
>
> China Belarus Hong Kong
>
> Israel Bulgaria
>
> Malta Paraguay
>
> France Czech Republic Switzerland Romania Puerto Rico Canada Germany
>
> Luxembourg
>
> Argentina
>
> Malaysia Croatia Singapore
>
> Oman
>
> Thailand
>
> Sweden Denmark Honduras

You'll notice that nearly all (except Turkey) falls back to the English display country name. Is this to be expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is correct. I got the same behavior running the code in my machine. It seems that JDK doesn't have Turkish translations for these country names except for Turkey itself.

Comment: Just tried IBM JDK 1.7 (the only 1.7 release I have), it returns turkish names for most of the countries...

Comment: @home, jdk 1.7.0_01 returns the same values are 1.6.0_29

Comment: Interesting - seems to be a feature we just should not use :-)

Comment: I tested on Oracle JDK 1.7. IBM JDK has more translations than Oracle's JDK. So I think this feature is vendor-dependent.